# Getting string from another string in Javascript

Tags: javascript, string, lastindexof

Please note that this is not a json object :) My string is:
`{"message":"***error in SAP module:-1***","status":400}`
This is not a json object, this is a pure string. I cannot turn it into a json object due to technical limitations.

So, I want to take only the bold string (all the value of "message").
I thought about lastIndexOf, and pick the string between ":" and ","
But I got messed up with the escape characters for the quotes.
How can I achieve it with lastIndexOf? Or in another better way?

Comment: There is no such thing as a JSON Object.  Objects are not JSON.  JavaScript Object Notation, is a string format for describing an object.  You just need to parse it.

Comment: If it is a string, then it *is* JSON. JavaScript objects are just that, and should better not be named "json object". So you have used the term in the opposite way than intended.

Comment: `JSON.parse('{"message":"error in SAP module:-1","status":400}').message` and done

Comment: Please elaborate on what the "technical limitations" are.

Comment: It **looks** like the string is valid JSON already.

Comment: Answering here because marked as duplicate. Maybe this could help in your specific case: 

`result = str.split(/{"message":"(.*)\:[-\d]*\"/m)[1];`

Answer (score 0):

If you can't use `JSON.parse`, I would use a regex to read it. You know you want the string directly following `"message":"`, so I would look for that, then grab everything from there to the next occurrence of `"`

Comment: Don't suggest regex for parsing JSON. If you find a regex to do that, I will give you JSON that will be a problem for it.

Comment: @trincot point taken. I'm still curious to hear from OP why `JSON.parse` isn't acceptable.